# Disable Matlab focus stealing, without modifying Matlab script

Tags: matlab

I hava Matlab script running in the background. It keeps popping up pogress bar windows as the computation progresses. This is very annoying.

Problem is I did not write the Matlab script myself, and it is a very long and complicated piece of code that I don't want to mess with. So how can I prevent Matlab from stealing focus, without modifying the Matlab script? Hopefully some Matlab setting will let me do this, without modifying the script itself.

In case it matters, my PC is running Xubuntu.

Comment: related: http://askubuntu.com/q/468262/234374. They are separate questions. At askubuntu I am asking for an Ubuntu setting. Here at SO I am asking for a Matlab setting.

Comment: I have seen related questions here at SO, but they are all about modifying the script to avoid the annoying windows. I can't modify the script here.

Comment: I was trying to reproduce the problem on windows, using this script: `while true,h=waitbar(0);for i=1:100,waitbar(i/100);end,close(h);end`, but it does not steal the focus. Does it steal the focus on ubuntu? Or can you provide a short example?

Comment: @Daniel Your example steals focus on ubuntu. Weird that this is not an issue on Windows.

Comment: Add `-nojvm` when starting MATLAB and see if it makes any positive difference.

Comment: @Divakar what's `-nojvm` supposed to do?

Comment: @becko I think it disables the figures, not sure how it differs from `-noFigureWindows`. Thought one could test out various options.

Comment: `-nojvm` does not load the JavaVM, most Figures require java. It indirectly suppressing Gui elements and is a nice way to avoid them in 3rd party toolboxes, which often don't care about `-noFigureWindows`.

Answer (score 3):

Some ideas to avoid figures:

Open a single worker (requires parallel computing) and run your script on it. Workers automatically don't have a GUI

```
matlabpool 1
warning('off','MATLAB:Completion:AllInputsExcluded') %turn off warning
spmd, yourfunction, end
```

Use the matlab startup parameters to disable figures

```
matlab -noFigureWindows
```

or start matlab as a command line tool, running your function, saving the workspace and exiting.

```
matlab -nodisplay -nosplash -r "yourfunction;save('result.mat');exit"
```

Comment: +1 using your last option right now.. thanks. Let's see if someone else comes up with a less hacky way :)